# Issue when starting wiremock-standalone using crontab

Tags: linux, cron, rhel, wiremock

I have a new regression suite that uses the Wiremock standalone JAR. In order to ensure this is running on the server, I have this script called checkwiremock.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cnt=$(ps -eaflc --sort stime | grep wiremock-standalone-2.11.0.jar |grep -v grep | wc -l)
if(test $cnt -eq 1);
then
    echo "Service already running..."
else
    echo "Starting Service"
    nohup java -jar /etc/opt/wiremock/wiremock-standalone-2.11.0.jar --port 1324 --verbose &
fi
```

The script works as expected when ran manually

```
./checkwiremock.sh
```

However when started using Crontab,

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /etc/opt/wiremock/checkwiremock.sh
```

Wiremock returns

> No response could be served as there are no stub mappings in this WireMock instance.

The only difference I can see between the manually started process and cron process is the TTY

```
root     31526  9.5  3.2 1309736 62704 pts/0   Sl   11:28   0:01 java -jar /etc/opt/wiremock/wiremock-standalone-2.11.0.jar --port 1324
root     31729 22.0  1.9 1294104 37808 ?       Sl   11:31   0:00 java -jar /etc/opt/wiremock/wiremock-standalone-2.11.0.jar --port 1324
```

Can't figure out what is wrong here.

Server details:
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

*Edit: corrected paths to ones actually used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the directory in the checkwiremock.sh to:

```
cd /path/to/shell/script
```

Comment: Great thanks! Could also include the --root-dir option

    java -jar /etc/opt/wiremock/wiremock-standalone-2.11.0.jar --port 1324 --root-dir /etc/opt/wiremock --verbose &